# How about + base verb / gerund

Tags: grammar

A: Do you want to clap your hands? 
B: No, shake.
A: you want to shake your hands? How about wiggle your fingers?

I think you use the gerund form after how about, but in a conversation like above, would the base form work ok, or it should always the ing form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How about wiggling your fingers?

can be used, or

> How about that you wiggle your fingers?

is also OK, and the *that* can be omitted, leading to

> How about you wiggle your fingers?

and in conversation, sometimes the subject can be omitted because of conversational elision, so you might hear *How about wiggle your fingers?*, but I would avoid writing that and even saying that unless the subject is clear from context.

But really the infinitive doesn't follow after *how about* when it is used like this - if you hear just the plain form of the verb, usually the subject should have been there but it was omitted.

But, it is possible to use the infinitive and *to* will be needed - consider this contrived example:

> I found this tool.  I don't know what it's used for.
>
> That's a strange tool.  Could it be used to fix broken windows?
>
> No, but how about to fix broken doors?  I bet it that's it's purpose.

*How* here is closer to it's literal meaning of *in what manner*, but you couldn't substitute *in what manner* when presenting alternatives to *Do you want to X?  How about Y?*.

Comment: this is a really old answer, but there is no omitted *that* here; "how about" isn't ever used with "that" as a conjunction, "how about we go out for a walk" is a grammatical sentence but "how about that we go for a walk" would be an error.

Comment: there is an answer that goes into some detail on this structure here https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/44967/how-about-someone-do-something

Comment: "How about that!" is a valid sentence, but here "that" is a pronoun, like "this",  "those", "it" etc.